# Extract Specific Data After a aggregation (Or any other solution for the desired result)

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, right-join

I want to select the Total "sales" of a specific "main_category" for the year 2016

**(main categories that don't have sales in that year should appear as zero)**

I have managed to select the "sales" of a specific "main category" with all the other "main_categories" *(that doesn't have any sales)* appearing as zero using below query:

```
SELECT 
    mc.name,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.no_of_units * b.unit_price),0) AS tCatSales
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Invoice i ON i.invoice_ID = s.invoice_id
INNER JOIN Inventory inv ON inv.inventory_ID = s.inventory_ID
INNER JOIN Batch b ON b.batch_ID = inv.batch_ID
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = b.product_ID
INNER JOIN Category c ON c.category_ID = p.category_id
RIGHT JOIN Main_Category mc ON mc.cat_id = c.main_category
--WHERE YEAR(i.trans_date) = 2016
GROUP BY mc.name
--HAVING YEAR(i.trans_date)=2016
```

but when I try to further segregate it **for year 2016 ONLY** either by **WHERE** clause or **HAVING** clause, it stops showing "main_category" names that have zero sales in the year.

One thing that I can think of is to give the query invoices only from 2016
which I tried to did by doing something like,

**Replacing the line:**
    `INNER JOIN Invoice i ON i.invoice_ID = s.invoice_id`

**with:**
`INNER JOIN Invoice i ON i.invoice_ID IN (SELECT invoice_id  FROM Invoice in2 WHERE Year(in2.trans_date)=2016)`

which **did** display the categories with zero values but with increased the calculated Sales Amount *(from 2069 to something 203151022.75)*.

I understand this addition is somewhat illogical and disrupts the whole Inner Joins but so far these are the closest thing I can think of or find on the web.

> **I REPEAT the desired result is: main categories that don't have sales in that year should appear as zero with the year given year/month/date**

Comment: Just posting a query and expecting other to solve it is not likely going to happen. We need more information to offer any real help here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ If you keep your where clause the way you have it your entire query logic changes to return only those rows with a match. I would start your entire query over and use Main_Category as your base table. Then left join all the other stuff. Right joins are confusing for even experienced people, they are downright flustering for other.

Comment: Why the right join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean and Eli mentioned, RIGHT JOIN is not recommended, you may change it to LEFT JOIN, OR use subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    mc.name,
    tCatSales = ISNULL(
      (
        SELECT 
            SUM(s.no_of_units * b.unit_price) AS tCatSales
        FROM Sales s
        INNER JOIN Invoice i ON i.invoice_ID = s.invoice_id
        INNER JOIN Inventory inv ON inv.inventory_ID = s.inventory_ID
        INNER JOIN Batch b ON b.batch_ID = inv.batch_ID
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = b.product_ID
        INNER JOIN Category c ON c.category_ID = p.category_id    
        WHERE mc.cat_id = c.main_category  
          AND YEAR(i.trans_date) = 2016
      ) , 0)
FROM Main_Category mc
```

Comment: Your suggestion of making a sub-query somewhat helped me in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WHERE ISNULL(YEAR(i.trans_date), 1) = 2016
```

if you put simple equals conditions on outer join it will eliminate nulls, which give zero-valued rows you desire.
Also note that something like:

```
WHERE YEAR(i.trans_date) = 2016
```

is not sargable, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)